# How can I use a diffrent style for emojis?

Tags: html, css, emoji

Many sites have their own emoji styles, how can you add your own emoji icons? Is there a library I have to add to my document or something related to `font-family`?

For instance, I'd like to add Twitter's emoji style to my website. Any ideas?

Comment: Those are unlikely to be `emoji`, but what's called "icon font" which is a bunch of SVGs packaged as glyphs of a font-file. [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app) is the most famous tool which can generate such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the rendering of emoji directly. Regardless of font-face, the user’s browser and OS determine how emoji characters are rendered.

But what you can do, is what Twitter and some other platforms do, which is to process the input text to *replace* emoji characters with any other image you would like.

[Check out this article with more info](https://dev.to/iamludal/you-are-using-emojis-the-wrong-way-i71), including a link to [Twemoji](https://twemoji.twitter.com/), a handy open source library by Twitter to handle this very problem.

Comment: Hi! Is there any way to change all emojis on the site? Like, not just a spesific position as the article you mentioned does.

Comment: @Bella I’m not sure exactly what you mean. In theory yes you can. If you are controlling the delivery of all content from the backend to the end user, you can intercept and replace all emoji Unicode characters before rendering.

Comment: Are there any tutorials or articles about that? ^~^

Comment: @Bella not that I’m aware of but the links I posted should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Emoji can be displayed with individual images (PNG, SVG...), but are often displayed using a color font.

- Android uses [Noto Color Emoji](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji)
- iOS and macOS use [Apple Color Emoji](https://emojipedia.org/apple/)
- Windows and XBox use [Segoe UI Emoji](https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/)
- Twitter uses [Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji)

Other platforms, apps or services may use other fonts, or individual images, or some combination thereof.

Fonts will use one of a handful of colour formats available in OpenType fonts. There's a useful summary of colour fonts [here](https://www.colorfonts.wtf/), though it is biased toward just one colour format (SVG—the page was written to promote a product used to produce that format), and it's out of date as it doesn't mention the most recent development in the OpenType format (a major enhancement to the COLR format).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for reaching out but that is not what im looking for. My question is how do I display those images to my website's emojis being visible to anyone?

Comment: You said you wanted to use Twitter's emoji style. So include the Twemoji font into your font stack.